# Touch events on React component in Chrome not captured unless desktop version is opened first

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, user-interface, mobile

I have a React website at [blogtheworld.co](https://blogtheworld.co) which displays pins on a world map. On desktop, when the user hovers over a pin a react-bootstrap 'popover' appears with more details (the react-bootstrap OverlayTrigger listens for both 'hover' and 'focus' events):

[image: Hovering over a pin in desktop mode opens the popover]

Additionally, when the user right-clicks somewhere on the map, a context menu opens with the option to add a post.

The code repository is [here](https://github.com/nomadiq-sw/blog-the-world) for anyone who wants to see the details.

When I open the site in Chrome for Android, the mobile version does not respond to either tapping on the pin for details or long-pressing the map for the context menu. Other touch events (on the button for filters in the top-right, or on the location search bar) are captured:

[image: Click on filter button on mobile opens dropdown menu]

Now, if I go to the Chrome menu and select 'Desktop site', the desktop site opens and touch events are detected. This in itself is not particularly surprising, but here's where things get really weird: if I subsequently go *back* to the mobile version of the site (by unchecking 'Desktop site' in Chrome), the touch events are now detected! I can tap on pins to open the popover:

[image: Popover is opened by touch event after switching to desktop version then back to mobile version]

Long-pressing to bring up the context menu also works.

Somehow, the process of switching from the mobile version to the desktop version and back to mobile 'tricks' Chrome into successfully detecting the events. Using developer tools to track the pointerDown events, I can see that there are `#document.pointerDown` and `DIV.pointerDown` events fired in both cases, but in the working version there are additional `BODY.pointerDown` events which are not fired in the non-working version. What I would like to know is, how can I modify my React code to enable the events to be detected by default?

Another important point to note: the site works fine on Firefox for Android and Safari for iOS.

EDIT (extra weirdness): when I run either the development or the production Docker container locally and access `localhost:<port>` from my phone via USB debugging, there is no problem. Similarly, the problem occurs whether I run the development or the production container on my DigitalOcean droplet. So this bug appears when the container is running on a DigitalOcean droplet, but not when *exactly the same container* (modulo differences introduced by different Docker versions) is running on `localhost`. Obviously this is impossible, and yet it is the case.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior on my iPhone, so it might just be an android browser bug. However maybe try setting `touch-action: none` in the CSS for each marker?

Comment: @DennisKats thanks for testing on iPhone (are you using Chrome or Safari?). It's good to know this issue really is specific to Chrome for Android. I'll try as you suggested and update here when I'm done.

Comment: I was testing on Safari, however currently on iOS, Chrome and Safari use the same underlying browser engine (WebKit). So it should hypothetically work for all iPhone users.

Comment: I tried with `touch-action: none` as suggested by @DennisKats, but the behavior is the same. See also the edit for extra weirdness; it's looking increasingly likely that this is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Can you review the network requests in Chrome on Android? Make sure the pre-flight Options calls aren’t being blocked somehow but being let through on desktop, which is allowing the pin data to be populated when you switch back to mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @TristanZimmerman. It seems neither Chrome nor Firefox dev tools currently show the OPTIONS calls explicitly, but in any case the GET is succeeding both on desktop and on mobile (moreover we can see that the data are definitely retrieved before the page is rendered, because the pins are positioned on the map according to the (lat, lng) which is in the body of the response to the GET request).